# trying to test API using postman

Tags: php, api, postman

i am trying to test an api using postman , each time i try to signup i keep getting "unexpected e".
Don't really know what is going on
here is my code:

```
$app->post('/signup', function() {
 $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
 $name = $app->request()->post('name');
 $email = $app->request()->post('email');
 $pass = $app->request()->post('pass');
 $app->response->setStatus(200);
 $app->response()->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 try
 {
 $db = getDB();
 $sth = $db->prepare("select count(*) as count from user WHERE email=:email");
$sth->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $sth->execute();
 $row = $sth->fetch();

 if($row['count']>0){
$output = array(
 'status'=>"0",
 'operation'=>"student already registered"
);
echo json_encode($output);
 $db = null;
return;
}
else{
```

// where i try to insert values into my database.

```
$sth = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO user (name, email,password)
VALUES(:name,:email,:pass)");
 $sth->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $sth->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $sth->bindParam(':pass', $pass, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
$output = array(
 'status'=>"1",
 'operation'=>"success"
);
echo json_encode($output);
 $db = null;
return;
}

}
catch(Exception $ex){
echo $ex;
}
});
```

Comment: What does your post body look like in postman? what kind of response back are you getting? 401? 403? 500?

Answer (score 0):

"unexpected e" happens because Postman was expecting the output to be a JSON response.

When you get the response, click the 'Raw' or 'Preview' tab. Or choose one of the other formats from the drop-down menu. You'll see the rest of the response.

[image: choose Raw, Preview or the drop down]